# Which information can be edited in App Store after submission?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

In case my app is being reviewed, or has already been approved (and thus is under `Ready For Sale` status or equivalent), which app information can I edit *without* having to submit a new version of the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html) there are some information that may be edited at any time, and a few that need to pass through through the whole app review process (which includes create a new app version and submit a new app binary) to be edited and approved to the App Store.

These can be edited at any time:

- Apple TV Privacy Policy
- License Agreement
- Whats New in This Version
- Description
- Support URL
- Marketing URL
- Copyright
- Trade rep
- Routing app coverage file

> To edit these information, select the Ready for Sale version from the platform header in the left pane, edit the desired fields and then click Save.

Now the information below cannot be edited when the app has already been approved, but may be editable if the app is under other statuses. To check if it is editable or not, go to yours iTunes Connect app page and see if the info is editable at that time. These are:

- App name
- Privacy Policy URL
- Primary Language
- Category
- App rating
- Bundle ID
- Screenshots
- Keywords
- Build
- App Preview
- Icons
- Version number
- Rating
- App review info
- Version release

Please note that after submission, the updated info may need up to 24 hours to reflect in the App Store.

This information is pretty useful when you're just depending on the App Store description translators in order to get your app live, for example. Just submit the app right away without the description (don't forget to set it to manual launch) and quicken up the review process.